# Convert SQL query to Django friendly format for application

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I have an SQL query thats runs on the Postgres database of my Django based webapp. The query runs against the data stored by Django-Notifications (a reusable app) and returns a list of email addresses that have not opted out of a specific notice type.

What I would really like to be able to do is to build an application that does this on demand, so I'm looking for an example of how to convert the SQL so it can run inside a Django view that will pass out a formatted email list. The SQL is currently thus:

```
gr_webapp=# select email from emailconfirmation_emailaddress where verified and user_id not in
(select user_id from notification_noticesetting s join notification_noticetype t on s.notice_type_id = t.id
where t.label = 'announcement' and not s.send);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to make appropriate adjustments as far as model names go, since you didn't show them in your question:

```
users_to_exclude = Noticesetting.objects.filter(send=False, notice_type__label='announcement').values('user')
emails = Emailaddress.objects.exclude(user__in=users_to_exclude)
```

Comment: I tried with a variation of your example but it gives "Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type."

users_to_exlude = NoticeSetting.objects.filter(notice_type='announcement').values('user') 

emails = EmailAddress.objects.exclude(user=users_to_exlude)
 print emails

Comment: Ah I see: I was doing it wrong - as you said:

 users_to_exlude = NoticeSetting.objects.filter(notice_type='announcement').values('user') 
 emails = EmailAddress.objects.exclude(user__in=users_to_exlude)